# How can I set up Eclipse to use ssh-agent for cvs?

Tags: eclipse, ssh, cvs

Several ways to ask this question:

- How can I get eclipse to use my ssh-config?
- How can I get eclipse to use /usr/bin/ssh instead of the internal implementation?  (I am not completely sure it does, but it does not read Host-entries in .ssh/config)

This is what I have tried:

- have CVS_ROOT in the environment eclipse starts in (I am asked for username and password, I know this setup works with command-line cvs)
- create a new repository location, with connection-type ext (message: unknown response received from cvs server: )
- same, with extssh (error: cannot locate host, which means that .ssh/config is not being read, I refer to a Host-alias defined there)
- same, but with the dns-name of the server, this time I'm asked for the passphrase for my id_rsa-file, so eclipse seems to be aware of atleast parts of my ssh-setup.  The passphrase-dialog is from eclipse, not the usual ssh-agent-dialog.

I am using eclipse 3.4.1 on ubuntu 08.10

Answer (score 2):

I expect you have looked at SSH in the Windows --> Preferences.

I have used ssh with eclipse. IIRC, I needed to add a key into

- Window --> Preferences --> General --> Network Connections --> SSH2.

You can also change the program you use for SSH (e.g. you don't trust the Java implementation of SSH) in

- Window --> Preferences --> Team --> CVS --> Ext Connection Method.

Comment: I can get pki to work using the internal ssh-implementation, but that doesn't utilise the ssh-agent. Using "ext" connection method is what I thought would be the correct procedure, but this gives me "unknown response received from cvs server".  So, yes, I have tried both of these alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse can use ssh-agent like this:

1. Window / Preferences / Team / CVS /Ext Connection Method
2. Select "Use an external program to connect"
3. CVS_RSH: ssh
4. Parameters: -l {user} {host}
5. CVS_SERVER: cvs

Pay attention that your cvs urls have "ext:" in there .cvs directory

This way eclipse just uses ssh like you do on your shell. If ssh-agent works inb your shell it works with eclipse too.